# How to record calls in android if its not permited for third-party apps and apps for that does exist in playstore

Tags: android, audio, phone-call, privacy, privacy-policy

Hi thanks for your time,

i have a application for sales force and my users are asking for call recording, in research for this issue i found the conclusion that this is not possible anymore because of privacy concerns, but looking on playstore i found applications for that.

So how is that possible that 3rd party apps are doing this if this is not possible for third-party apps?

One permission to do the feature is CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT that is not permitted to be used :

[image: CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT not for use by third-party applications.]

Is there any way of doind something like this? every tutorial i follow lead to no success.

Comment: I understand that only is possible if the smartphone is rooted... maybe is tricky but maybe is possible to use REMOTE_SUBMIX from MediaRecorder.AudioSource simulating a stream data to save the conversation... i don´t know.

Comment: Fine. It is not possible. But Samsung Device having Inbuilt Call Recorder Functionality.  One Plus also having the option to record a call. Is there any way to trigger an inbuilt call recording function?

Comment: only if it is documented by the manufacturer, i believe you will have no sucess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok that is not possible, the applications from play store that has this feature just do not work anymore, only on old versions of android.